# Why does (pr-str Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY) return different responses?

Tags: clojure

On some machines running `(pr-str Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)` returns `"Infinity"` which is what I expect.

However on some machines running the same `(pr-str Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)` returns `"Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY"`

We've eliminated jvm versions, all are running Clojure 1.6, we've tried eliminating .lein/profiles.clj, but we're at a loss as to what causes this discrepancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's no way for `(pr-str Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)` to return `"Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY"` in a vanilla Clojure environment. It could only do that if you've loaded some library which does some serious mucking with `print-method`. Alternatively it could do that if you make a mistake in writing it, eg if you wrote `(pr-str 'Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)` instead you would get that result.

Try loading up an absolute bare-bones Clojure repl on the machines returning a weird result, via `java -cp /path/to/clojure.jar`, and paste `(pr-str Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)` into them. I would be quite surprised if you could still reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Still don't know _why_ this is happening, but sure enough running from the same jar in my m2 directory works, where `lein repl` doesn't. Thank you.